# moveCamera doesn't work after onPlaceSelected()

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I have tried the following code to update my mapFragment (Google Maps API V2) to the location chosen from the autoCompleteFragment (Google Places API), the marker change well but the camera remain on previous location.

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment=(PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autoComplete);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            LatLng autoCompleteLatLng=place.getLatLng();
            Location newLoc=new Location("New");
            newLoc.setLatitude(autoCompleteLatLng.latitude);
            newLoc.setLongitude(autoCompleteLatLng.longitude);
            onLocationChanged(newLoc);
        }

private void handleNewLocation(Location location){
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    map.addMarker(options);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10.0f));
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    handleNewLocation(location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your project, setting breakpoints and ensure your `handleNewLocation` method is being executed. Then, you must check that your [`myLocation`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location) object has valid latitude and longitude values. The camera won't move if it is null.

Here's a related SO ticket, you may try to use the work around given by community: [Android google map v2 moveCamera doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128583/android-google-map-v2-movecamera-doesnt-work?rq=1)

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work. I had put som logs for debug, and it has bot correct lat and long but does not update the camera